# Book where rat-like aliens invade Earth and enslave humanity

Tags: story-identification, aliens, mind-control

What's the name of the book where a race of rat like aliens invade Earth and enslave humans using mind control?

Comment: That's an interesting question, but more details would help. When did you read this story? (so we can roughly estimate the publication date)  Do you remember any characters or plot twists?

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this one?

CHANDLER, A. BERTRAM

*[Contraband from Otherspace](http://www.baenebooks.com/p-741-contraband-from-otherspace.aspx)*  (Ace, 1967, bound with Reality Forbidden by Philip E. High. (Ace, 1979, bound with Into the Alternate Universe. Magazine title was The Edge of Night.)

[image: Book cover]

Rim series.

Grimes encounters a derelict ship that has drifted into our universe from a parallel one where ratlike aliens have enslaved the human race.  Even worse, the aliens are aware of our continuum and are making plans to invade.

Answer (score 2):

"... aliens ... enslave humans using mind control ..." is a fairly common device in science fiction. More details might help narrow this down.

Maybe you're looking for Heinlein's ***[The Puppet Masters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Puppet_Masters)***? It's been a while since I read it, but aliens landing on Earth and using mind control was the basis of the plot. My memory of the aliens was more worm-like (the Wikipedia article describes them as "slugs"), but I don't remember Heinlein's description, so rat-like might be more accurate, or at least one way of imagining them.